# How does the Exp. Share distribute Effort Values to non-participators?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I'm trying to EV train my Shuckle in Pokemon Alpha Sapphire, specifically, it's defense stat. Which means I have to massacre some Sandshrew. That's hard to do with a Shuckle, which is a Pokemon with a very low attack and sp. attack. I did some research and learned that the Exp. Share will share not only Exp, but EVs as well. I would love to have Rayquaza kill the Sandshrews, but I don't know exactly how the EVs are distributed. 
Basically, do Pokemon who haven't actually participated in battle get 100% of the EVs gained, or only 50%, as is the case with Exp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every Pokémon that receives Experience Points is given full EVs as well.